# Leaflet setView by ajax (cityname or postalCode)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

We are trying to switch to Leaflet from gmaps.
SEtting up the map worked fine, markers for all our stores work, too.
I used leaflet-search for this build-in solution for searching for cities.

But it is working on keyPress or sth like that.

We want to have an input with a separate button for submitting.

Earlier, we just used an ajax, with a certain url from gmaps, and appended the searchvalue.
But with Leaflet I just cannot make it ...
It looked like this:

```
function geocode(key)
{
var address = key.replace(/ /g, '+');
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json';
url += "?key=" + SitePreferences.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY;

$.ajax({
    url     : url,
    data    : {address:address},
    dataType: "json",
    success : function (json)
    {
        setGeocode(json);
    },
    error: function()
    {
        console.log("Google map API geocode error");
    }
});}
```

How do I do that with leaflet ?
I tried sth like that without success though:

```
var url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={address}';

        $.ajax(
        {
             url:url, 
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data)
             {
                 console.log(data),
             }
        });
```

Comment: after `console.log(data),` you should have `;` not `,` and you will see the data

Comment: That was just a typo from copying the code, since I removed some company-related things.
What I get in return is an array with funny places like "display_name: "313, The Address, Mauá, São Caetano do Sul, Região Imediata de São Paulo, Região Metropolitana de São Paulo, Região Intermediária de São Paulo, São Paulo, Südosten, Brasilien". Although I searched for "berlin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was fine, it had a syntax error, i also sent the params using data instead of directly from the url

```js
$('#find').click(function(){
  var url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search';
  $.ajax(
  {
    url: url, 
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
      format:'json',
      q: '{' + $("#address").val() + '}'
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
       console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="address" />
<button id="find">find address</button>
```